# How to change IBM Lotus Notes Client preferences via API?

Tags: java, eclipse, api, lotus-notes, lotusscript

Is there a way to programmatically change Lotus Notes client preferences?  Notes clients usually choose File, Preferences to bring up to the Preferences dialog box.

There are a few Preferences that we'd like to confirm are set, and if not, set them -- like in the Widgets category, make sure 'Show Widget Toolbar and the My Widgets panel' is selected.

Where are these Preferences settings stored?  Can they be modified via LotusScript, Java, or .INI file modifications?

I do know that Domino admins can create Policy documents that can configure Notes clients desktops, but I did not see an option for enabling the Widget toolbar.  This would be a good way to roll out our packages, but I would like to have a script to change the widget preferences that the client can run locallys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Many preferences are stored in notes.ini. To test if this is the case for the preference you are talking about, make a backup of your notes.ini, then start the Notes client, change the setting, quit the client, and diff the notes.ini against the backup that you made